# (Proof Explanation of :) Under what conditions are there only a finite number of distinct subsets $S$ of a subspace $W$ such that $S$ generates $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, proof-explanation

Let $W$ be a subspace of a vector space $V.$ Under what conditions are there only a finite number of distinct subsets $S$ of $W$ such that $S$ generates $W$ ?

This is a question from the book Linear Algebra by Stephen H Friedberg, Insel and Spence from the chapter named Vector Spaces.

The solution given on the solution manual of this book is:

> When $W$ has finite element the statement holds. Otherwise $W − \{v\},$ where $v ∈ W$ will be a generating set of $W.$ But there are infinitely many $v ∈ W.$

However, I don't get this solution completely. The first sentence, "When $W$ has finite element the statement holds" looks ambiguous. I think they meant: "When $W$ has finite **number of** element**s** the statement holds"

With this modification of the first line of the given solution, it makes a quite sense for it there existed infinite number of subsets $S$ of $W$ such that $S$ generates $W,$ then the set $W$ has infinite number of elements as all the elements of the sets $S$ are in $W$ and this is a contradiction. So, the first sentence seems to be correct.

Is this modification of the first sentence of the given solution, **precisely valid?**

Now, for the second sentence in the solution, "Otherwise $W − \{v\},$
where $v ∈ W$ will be a generating set of $W$" , I dont understand why  $W − \{v\},$ (,where $v ∈ W$) will be a generating set of $W$? Nowhere, is it mentioned that "every element in $W$ is a  linear combination of the *other* vectors in $W$". This is the part that seems absurd to me.

Any help regarding these two issues will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the first sentence should be "number of". For the second, pick any $w\neq v$, $w\neq 0$. Then neither $w$ nor $v-w$ are equal to $v$, they both lie in $W$, and $v=(v-w)+w$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless $W$ consists of exactly two vectors (which can only occur in a one dimensional space over a field with two elements), for every $v\in W$ we have $v\in\mathrm{span}(W-\{v\})$.

Indeed, if $W$ contains more than $v$ and $0$, pick $w\in W-\{v,0\}$. Then $v-w\neq v$ and $w\neq v$, so $w,v-w\in W-\{v\}$. And we can express $v$ as a linear combination of these two vectors,
$$v=(v-w)+w.$$
In particular this happens when $W$ has infinitely many elements.

Yes, the first sentence should read "finite number of elements".

Comment: Thank you so much! +1 from me for this nice explanation.